# highcharts with lots of data render blank in pdf use wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, wicked-pdf

wicked_pdf render highcharts well in pdf when you disable the follow options:

enableMouseTracking: false, shadow: false, animation: false

But recently I encount a problem: when the stacked and grouped column with a little more data, it render blank in pdf. (Same charts with a little data render ok in pdf!)

The normal chart:
[image]

The charts in pdf:
[image]

Anyone can help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with highcharts and wicked PDF, but with a different js chart i had a similar problem. I fixed it by resizing it, the chart wouldn't fit the pdf so it wasn't rendered

Comment: Thanks buddy, you are right! When I set to the original width twice as long, the charts render ok again!